# Calculate md5 hash based on file contains(means without filename)

Tags: java, scala, hash, md5

I'm trying to calculate an MD5 hash based on the file contents, not the file name. In my code below while calculating MD5 hash on two files with different file names but identical contents it is generating two different MD5 hash values. I expected the same hash value.

Code

```
 def computeMD5Hash(path: String): String = {
          val buffer = new Array[Byte](8192)
          val md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")

          val dis = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)), md5)
          try {
            while (dis.read(buffer) != -1) {}
          } finally {
            dis.close()
          }

          md5.digest.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
        }

println(computeMD5Hash("/Users/xxxx/Documents/Project/yyy/de/src/main/resources/input/xxxxx_list_01.txt"))
   println(computeMD5Hash("/Users/xxxx/Documents/Project/yyy/de/src/main/resources/input/xxxxx_list_03.txt"))
```

Output

```
10d34fcb95ca6714fb00dae12527be4e
651c8eaf62016182d2a39c5442a339a8
```

Expected Output

```
10d34fcb95ca6714fb00dae12527be4e
10d34fcb95ca6714fb00dae12527be4e
```

Comment: I've used _exactly_ the function you have successfully for some deploy scripts. It is correct. Suggestion: try calling `md5 -q /Users/xxxx/Documents/Project/yyy/de/src/main/resources/input/problem_list_01.txt`. The output should match your functions output.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and it works for me. Are you sure that the files are equal?
Does it work if you take one file explicitly copy-paste it to another location and run your program?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really an answer but more of a comment. One tip-off: no answer should ever contain a question.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk got it